# Authorize.net Can create CIM customer profile in Hosted form iframe

Tags: xml, iframe, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

Right now, I Create Customer profile by passing xml request, and after create payment profile using hosted iframe, but is it possible to create Customer profile in hosted iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have to create customer profile first by passing XML request and then using this id you will be able to open the add payment detail form in the iframe,
because you need a token for it, and without a customer profile id you cant get a token request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Page 102 of the [CIM Guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/CIM_XML_guide.pdf) specifically states that you can. See page 103 of the CIM Guide for how to do this.

> The following HTML code adds a button labeled “Add a New Payment
>   Method” which, when clicked, opens an iframe:
>
> `<button onclick="AuthorizeNetPopup.openAddPaymentPopup()">Add a New
>   Payment Method</button>`

Comment: hi John, this popup create payment profile not Customer profile :(